# Google App Engine - Codeigniter redirect issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

I've created an application using codeigniter framework and its working fine on my localhost and staging server. However, on Google app engine the admin panel doesn't load at all. It goes into a redirect loop. Not sure what is the issue. The app.yaml looks like this:

```
application: myproject-2015
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
# - url: /favicon\.ico
#   static_files: favicon.ico
#   upload: favicon\.ico


 - url: /bootstrap
   static_dir: myproject/bootstrap

 - url: /admin/css
   static_dir: myproject/admin/css

 - url: /admin/images
   static_dir: myproject/admin/images

 - url: /admin/js
   static_dir: myproject/admin/js

 - url: /admin/.*
   script: myproject/admin/index.php
```

Comment: Can you provide any details on the urls involved in the redirect loop? Does it occur with a request to anything under `/admin/`?

Comment: Yes whenever i try to access the admin panel like myproject/admin it goes into a redirect loop. My default controller is set as login controller. The same thing works fine on localhost and on staging server. I think the issue is with the app.yaml file.

Comment: Are you using custom domain? Is this your entire app.yaml or an excerpt?

Comment: Nope. This is not the complete yaml.

Comment: Didn't find a solution for this. Contacted google support but no use. So finally moved the code on Amazon. Google app engine is still not ready for PHP.